# How does Jam.js manage `shim` package

Tags: javascript, package, jamjs

I was wondering how Jam.js (the package system) was managing packages who aren't published by their authors. (like Backbone or Handlebars)

I looked at the [documentation](http://jamjs.org/docs) but found nothing over there. But in the package list, we can see that some packages aren't published by their authors, example [Handlebars](http://jamjs.org/packages/#/details/handlebars).

How are those added? Can you setup yourself URL to fetch `shim` packages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without answers, I've been suggesting the idea on Github `jam` repo: https://github.com/caolan/jam/issues/111

Everyone can package an app for its author, this will make them available on jam. But it's not yet possible to set local configuration to fetch packages from github (maybe in future version).